# wpf Custom panel xaml name is not declared in namespace

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I made custom panel, CustomCanvas class enxtending Canvas class in namespace canvase.
And I add

xmlns:local="clr-namespace:canvase"

and

```
<StackPanel>

                             <local:CustomCanvas x:Name="CustomCanvas" MaxHeight="1555">
                            </local:CustomCanvas>

</StackPanel>
```

Then it show

Name "CustomCanvas" is not declared in namespace "clr-namespace:canvase"

So, i don't see wpf design view, for WYSIWYG.

Please help

Comment: Sometimes you need to build the project before the designer can display the component. Check if the namespace is right too.

Comment: I build solution.  But same...   However when i compile and execute , not problem in this project and execute well.

Comment: But i can't see design view...

Comment: Are you sure that your `CustomCanvas` is in `canvase` namespace, not `canvas` nor `your.application.canvas` namespace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your Platform Target for your project (Project Properties -> Build) is set to Any CPU.